# System.MissingMethodException when trying to read ZipFile from ZipArchive C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-ziparchive

I have a C# .NET (v4.6.2) WinForms app where I'm accessing a file that may/may not be a .zip archive that was created using "System.IO.Compression;". I have both "System.IO.Compression" and System.IO.Compress.FileSystem" references in the project and "using System.IO.Compression;" at the top, which was installed using the NuGet package Installer.

Below is the code for attempting to open the file as a .zip archive:

```
      try
        {
            string extractPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            string strGameVersion = "";
            string strProjectType = "";

            using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(OpenFilePath))
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(extractPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.FullName.Contains("ProjectData.txt"))
                    {
                        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));
                        strGameVersion = sr.ReadLine();
                        strProjectType = sr.ReadLine();
                    }
                    File.Delete(extractPath);
                }
                sr.Close();
                fs.Close();
                archive.Dispose();
            }
    }
    catch(System.IO.FileFormatException flex1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(flex1.ToString(), "oops.", MessageBoxButtons.OK,  MessageBox.Icon.Error);
    }
```

The error message is "System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(System.String)'."
So what am I doing wrong or not doing at all?

Answer (score 10):

For some reason, `OpenRead` does not exist in `net46` assembly.
The quick workaround is to use

```
ZipArchive OpenRead(string filename)
{
    return new ZipArchive(File.OpenRead(filename), ZipArchiveMode.Read);
}
```

as answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44598092/75947

Answer (score 1):

I had to switch over to using System.IO.Compression from nuget.org to get this to work. Plus I had to make the changes that Felix suggested above. That is replace:

`ZipFile.OpenRead(file))`

with

`new ZipArchive(File.OpenRead(file), ZipArchiveMode.Read)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, I'm presuming that dependency assemblies trying to load may be incorrect version of it. In order to tell them you're going to have to check the fusion binding log to see what happened. Below tutorial tells on how to debug assembly binding failures to detect their root cause.

http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx